# css - set different styles to other nodes where the class applies

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to set different styles to the same class (when it appears for the second time in the markup) using the Subsequent-sibling combinator "~" but it seems it didn't work , maybe I'm omitting a detail with the use of "~" , also... Unfortunately I cannot change the html because it is generated by a cms

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mosaic big">
      <div>Red</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mosaic medium">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mosaic big">
      <div>Blue</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mosaic medium">
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css
.root > .container > .mosaic.big {
  color: red
}

```
.root > .container > .mosaic.big ~ .root > .container > .mosaic.big {
  color: blue
}
```

also... here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chinoche/wd1rhg11/
Thanks in advance

Comment: the elements must have the same parent for `~` to work. Could you explain with more details what you want to achieve? your CSS is not enough for us to undestand, because it's written on false assumptions (`mosaic.big` never happens twice in the same parent)

Comment: with the actual  structure and if i consider the fact that the classes can be at any container i would say there is no way with CSS ... consider JS

Comment: yes, I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it using css selectors, well... it's time for a little js, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Try this styling.

```
.root > .container > .mosaic.big {
  color: red
}

.root > .container:nth-child(3) > .mosaic.big {
  color: blue
}
```

OR

```
.root > .container > .mosaic.big {
  color: red
}

.root > .container:nth-child(n+2) > .mosaic.big {
  color: blue
}
```

Comment: Anything that the voter found wrong here ? Or the code did not work.

Comment: well he said : *when it appears for the second time in the markup* .. and you selector is specific as it select the 3rd container ... so what if it's not in the 3rd but the second ?

Comment: @arhak he said *when it appears for the second time in the markup* .. he doesn't specifiy he has a modulo or regular thing

Comment: Well, @TemaniAfif since OP is bound by CMS output, we are quite sure that 3rd `.container` WILL and ALWAYS contain the element which needs to be styled. Any issues ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif he didn't say otherwise either and as rach8garg points out, there is a CMS with preset HTML structure in play

Comment: he said when it appears the second time .. actually you are supposing that this is the final structure of his HTML and yes in this case it would be easy to target the second one since we know where is the second one ... but the OP doens't know. Well if the OP agree with this will remove my downvote ;) as in this case the whole question is bad written

Comment: but anyway, this answer brings insight to a "possible" solution, which might be valid or not, depending on whether the OP accepts it

Comment: What is the solution that you propose @TemaniAfif ? If we do not suppose the HTML structure, even in that case you have issues !!

Comment: @rach8garg  I'll make sure if this is the html structure, if not as Temani said, it's better to use some js

Comment: the HTML the OP show is not the FINAL html .. the structure is the same BUT the `big` classes can be everywhere inside any of the containers. This is the deal, we don't know where the big will be and how many we will have. You code work in a particular case

Comment: it seems the big/medium classes are coming from a CMS, for me that pretty much stable when you're addressing a CSS for that specific scenario

Comment: @arhak so in this case the OP should update his question. If yes or no the structure is the same .. and saying "no you cannot" is also a valid answer as sometimes we have to rely on some JS to do something we cannot do with CSS ;)

Answer (score 1):

From what ather answers suggested, i assumed this is what you want (you can comment if it doesn't fit edge cases):

So as i said, `~` only works with elements that have the same parent.

Note: it doesn't make it blue because it's the second `.mosaic.big` in a container, but because the container itself is not the first. To have a fully working solution without experimental features, you should need JS

CSS:

```
.root > .container > .mosaic.big {
  color: red
}

.root > .container ~ .container > .mosaic.big {
  color: blue
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wd1rhg11/5/

Answer (score -1):

Sadly without changing the html you will not be able to use the subsequent sibling selector

The CSS next sibling selector will only match the immediate siblings of the class to the left of the operator. So for this to work the elements you use with this operator must have the same parent.

In addition the matching on the right hand side will begin at the element matched on the left hand side therefore you dont need to add the parent structure

```
.root > .container > .mosaic.big {
  color: red
}

.root > .container > .mosaic.big ~ .mosaic.big {
  color: blue
}
```

See updated

https://jsfiddle.net/wd1rhg11/4/

You may be able to acheive what you are trying to with javascript if possible

Comment: he said : *Unfortunately I cannot change the html because it is generated by a cms*

Comment: thanks a lot! I should've read the proper use for the sibling selector

Answer (score -1):

You can use nth-child(n) of '.mosaic' class:

```
.root > .container > .mosaic:nth-child(1).big {
  color: red;
}
.root > .container > .mosaic:nth-child(3).big {
  color: blue;
}
```

here`s jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsilent/w8jjjsbz/